# How should I rewrite the code?

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
<?php
$original_chars = array(
    '/A/','/B/','/C/'
);
$replaced_chars = array(
    'a','b','c'
);
$updated_filename = preg_replace( $original_chars, $replaced_chars, $filename );
?>
```

I need to combine two arrays with chars into one associative array.

**How should I rewrite the line with preg_replace from previous code sample?**

```
<?php
$array_chars = array(
    '/A/' => 'a',
    '/B/' => 'b',
    '/C/' => 'c'
);
//$updated_filename = preg_replace( $original_chars, $replaced_chars, $filename );
?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite it? Is it not working?

Comment: `array_keys()`, `array_values()`

Comment: I would rewrite it in Klingon

Comment: @itamar It is working, but I need to rewrite it because the arrays are very huge and the code is not readable now.

Comment: OH! Now I get what you were looking for. The question wasn't so clear.Looks like @RyanS has a good answer down there.

Comment: @zerkms nm completely misunderstood the question :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `array_keys` and `array_values` (untested)

```
$updated_filename = preg_replace( array_keys($original_chars), array_values($replaced_chars), $filename );
```

Answer (score 1):

First at all the best way to do that is `strtr()`

```
$filename = strtr($filename, "ABC", "abc");
```

or

```
$array_chars('A' => 'a', 'B' => 'b', 'C' => 'c');
$filename = strtr($filename, $array_chars);
```

For the use of preg_replace with an associative array, you must `use array_keys()`:

```
$result = preg_replace(array_keys($array_chars), $array_chars, $filename);
```

(note that this way is not very usefull and that `array_values()` is not needed.)

Comment: "this way is not very usefull" --- any details on this?

Comment: There is no real advantage to use array_keys instead of creating two separate arrays.

Comment: there is - one array instead of 2 - it's easier to handle and manage